# Error in Loading Css codes

Tags: css, load

I moved whole ASP.Net website folder into another location, now when I run it, there is an error in loading css files, I have Master page which loads Css files, and other pages should use it, but when I debug the page with FireBug, there is no rule in .css files which this page used them. why is it happenning??

my website Structure
my Folder/style/main.css
mu folfer/js/jquery-1.10.1.min

in my master page I use this Code

```
  <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css" />
  <script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js")%>'></script>
```

in Firebug , there is this message when I click on each Css file in Css Part.

**There are no rules. You can create a rule.**

Comment: Please paste folder structure and relevant code :)\

Comment: This usually means your CSS files are either empty or not found, are you sure the stylesheets have content and that they're are in the correct location?

Comment: @Jatin : I updated the codes, here is my structure.

Comment: @Fabio this website is working on the first location now, I 've just copy it into new location

Comment: by the way, I found out the scripts are not loading too!!!